# How to get Default collation details for pgsql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am trying to get the default collation details (column level as in mysql). Is it possible to fetch such details?

I have tried using this [link](https://www.dbi-services.com/blog/collations-in-postgresql-basics/) as reference and only able to see all the collation as a catalogue and I'm not sure is this the right way!!

Answer (score 1):

This answer only talks about PostgreSQL.

Let's have an example that I can use to demonstrate how it works:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (
   col1 text,
   col2 text COLLATE "tr-TR-x-icu"
);
```

`col1` is using the default collation, `col2` is defined with the Turkish ICU collation.  We can see that using `psql` with the `\d` metacommand:

```
\d tab
               Table "laurenz.tab"
 Column │ Type │  Collation  │ Nullable │ Default 
════════╪══════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═════════
 col1   │ text │             │          │ 
 col2   │ text │ tr-TR-x-icu │          │
```

Now what is the default collation? It is the collation of the database. We can see that with `\l`:

```
\l test
                                                  List of databases
 Name │  Owner  │ Encoding │ Locale Provider │  Collate   │   Ctype    │ ICU Locale │ ICU Rules │  Access privileges  
══════╪═════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════════
 test │ laurenz │ UTF8     │ icu             │ de_AT.utf8 │ de_AT.utf8 │ de-AT      │           │ =c/laurenz         ↵
      │         │          │                 │            │            │            │           │ laurenz=CTc/laurenz
```

So the default collation is `de-AT`, the Austrian German ICU collation, and that is used for `col1` by default.

Comment: And if you start psql with the `-E` flag you can see the queries it runs for its backslash commands.